# Use two indexers to access values in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame (`df`) with many columns and rows.

What I'd like to do is access the values in one column for which the values in two other columns match my indexer.

This is what my code looks like now:

```
df.loc[df.delays == curr_d, df.prev_delay == prev_d, 'd_stim']
```

In case it isn't clear, my goal is to select the values in the column `'d_stim'` for which other values in the same row are `curr_d` (in the `'delays'` column) and `prev_d` (in the `'prev_delay'` column).

This use of `loc` does not work.  It raises the following error:

```
/home/despo/dbliss/dopa_net/behavioral_experiments/analysis_code/behavior_analysis.py in plot_prev_curr_interaction(data_frames, labels)
   2061             for k, prev_d in enumerate(delays):
   2062                 diff = np.array(df.loc[df.delays == curr_d,
-> 2063                                        df.prev_delay == prev_d, 'd_stim'])
   2064                 ind = ~np.isnan(diff)
   2065                 diff_rad = np.deg2rad(diff[ind])

/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1292 
   1293         if type(key) is tuple:
-> 1294             return self._getitem_tuple(key)
   1295         else:
   1296             return self._getitem_axis(key, axis=0)

/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_tuple(self, tup)
    787 
    788         # no multi-index, so validate all of the indexers
--> 789         self._has_valid_tuple(tup)
    790 
    791         # ugly hack for GH #836

/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _has_valid_tuple(self, key)
    139         for i, k in enumerate(key):
    140             if i >= self.obj.ndim:
--> 141                 raise IndexingError('Too many indexers')
    142             if not self._has_valid_type(k, i):
    143                 raise ValueError("Location based indexing can only have [%s] "

IndexingError: Too many indexers
```

What is the appropriate way to access the data I need?

Comment: `df.loc[(df.delays == curr_d) & (df.prev_delay == prev_d), 'd_stim'])` or `df.loc[(df.delays == curr_d) & (df.delays.shift() == prev_d), 'd_stim'])` if you don't have `prev_delay` column?

Comment: @dbliss. You have a very straightforward boolean selection question that was answered correctly by MaxU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your logic isn't working for two reasons.

1. pandas doesn't know what to do with comma separated conditions

   > df.delays == curr_d, df.prev_delay == prev_d
2. Assuming you meant `and` you need to wrap these up in parenthesis and join with `&`.  This is @MaxU's solution in the comments and should work unless you haven't given us everything.
   `df.loc[(df.delays == curr_d) & (df.prev_delay == prev_d), 'd_stim'])`

However, I think this looks prettier.

```
df.query('delays == @curr_d and prev_delay == @prev_d').d_stim
```

If this works then so should've @MaxU's.  If neither work, I suggest you post some sample data because most folk don't like guessing what your data is.